# Python: Storing a string into an array seems to shift the string indices?

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am trying to store strings of data for ocr detection using naive bayes. The data is a string with dimensions 29 X 28. It looks something like this:

```
        ++#####++       
    ++######++          
    ####+++             
    +##                 
    +##+                
     +#+                
     +#++++             
    +######++           
   +###+++####+         
   +#+     ++###+       
              +##+      
               +##+     
                +##+    
                 +##    
                  +#    
                 +##    
    ++          ++#+    
   +#+      ++++##+     
   +###++#+#####++      
    +++####++++
```

To read and store such data into an array of integers I try to `.replace` '#' and '+' with '1' and '\n' and blank spaces by 0. However, when I try to reconstruct the image after reading into an array. What I get is this:

```
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]          
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I don't understand why I am getting a garbled output. The code I am using is:

```
lines = data.read()


def split28(s, n):
    for begin in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield s[begin:begin+n]


zoenum = []         #strings are immutable
val_zoenum = []


for digit in split28(lines, 812):
    zoenum.append(digit)

for i in range(len(zoenum)):
        zoenum[i] = zoenum[i].replace("\n", " ")        
        zoenum[i] = zoenum[i].replace("+", "1").replace("#", "1").replace(" ", "0")
        zoenum[i] = list(map(int, zoenum[i]))
```

zoenum is a list of such strings of data. Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated. Also, if I need to restructure the question, please tell me.

Comment: are you sure the input does not contain tabs or any non-space whitespace?

Comment: Hard to say. `data.read()` doesn't give you a list of lines, it gives you a big string, which can be interpreted as an iterator of characters.

Comment: Input does contain white spaces(blanks) which I replace by 0s. @Tommy

Comment: Yes, that's why I am converting it into a list of integers. @Eric Duminil

Comment: @Karan I said any non-space whitespace. E.g., a tab.

Comment: In your example code you don't use `lines` anywhere.  Why do you have it?  What does `zoenum` contain?  What is the output of `print(repr(zoenum))` before running your loop?  And after?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, it does contain '\n' - newline @Tommy

Comment: lines is basically a huge string of such data. I split it into 29 x 28 chunks which I store in zoenum[i]. @Steven Rumbalski

Comment: @EricDuminil - Your code works perfectly however, I don't understand why mine doesn't. I mean you are looping through the list using .splitlines while I use .replace. Why does that make a difference?

Comment: @Karan: To be honest, I don't really understand your code. But `lines` aren't lines in your code, just characters in a huge string. The string hasn't 29x28 but 24x20 dimensions. If you use `for digit in split28(lines, 25):` instead of `for digit in split28(lines, 812):`, it looks better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that what you call `line` really is a line. If you have a file object, use `readlines()` instead of `read`, or this syntax:

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
        # do something with line
```

It might be easier to create a new list with a comprehension instead of trying to modify a list in place.

Here's an example with a data included inside the script:

```
text = """        ++#####++
    ++######++
    ####+++
    +##
    +##+
     +#+
     +#++++
    +######++
   +###+++####+
   +#+     ++###+
              +##+
               +##+
                +##+
                 +##
                  +#
                 +##
    ++          ++#+
   +#+      ++++##+
   +###++#+#####++
    +++####++++         """

for line in text.splitlines():
    print([0 if x == ' ' else 1 for x in line])
```

It outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

With :

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    print(''.join('0' if x == ' ' else '1' for x in line))
```

It outputs:

```
000000001111111110000000
000011111111110000000000
000011111110000000000000
000011100000000000000000
000011110000000000000000
000001110000000000000000
000001111110000000000000
000011111111100000000000
000111111111111000000000
000111000001111110000000
000000000000001111000000
000000000000000111100000
000000000000000011110000
000000000000000001110000
000000000000000000110000
000000000000000001110000
000011000000000011110000
000111000000111111100000
000111111111111111000000
000011111111111000000000
```

Note that the dimensions are 24x20, not 29x28.

Comment: You should change `x is ' '` to `x == ' '` since you mean to test for equality not identity. (It may be a nice implementation detail that Python is interning a single character string, but I think that should probably be saved as a possible later optimization.)